# 3d animation for python 3.4

Tags: animation, python-3.x

I've been animating evolution of surfaces (stored as 3d numpy arrays) using matplotlib, but this method is slow and clunky.  I gather that VPython and MayaVi are better alternatives, but apparently neither is available yet in Python 3.4 (which is what I'm using).  Are there any good ways to perform 3d animation in Python 3.4?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the *vpython* working in *python3.4* now. Follow this steps:

**Preparation**

Download the four packages  **TTFQuery**, **FontTools**, and **Polygon** ,**vpython** in [get the requisites packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) to same directory.

**Installation**

1. Run cmd
2. `cd path/to/package_downloaded_directory`
3. `pip install packagename.whl`
4. Find the file `C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\vis\materials.py`
5. Open the file in an editor, then go to line 70
6. Comment the two lines just like this

   ```
   class raw_texture(cvisual.texture):
         def __init__(self, **kwargs):
             cvisual.texture.__init__(self)
   #              for key, value in kwargs.items():
   #                  self.__setattr__(key, value)
   ```
7. Save the changes

   Note that when when you use vpython to code a script, the first line must be like below:

   ```
   from vis import *
   ```
8. Below is my code sample

   ```
   from vis import *
   sphere(pos=vector(0,0,0),radius=0.5,color=color.red)
   arrow(pos=vector(0.5,0,0),axis=vector(1,0,0),color=color.green)
   ```